# Ubuntu 13.10 fails to suspend on closing laptop lid

Tags: power-management

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E330. Before upgrading to 13.04, when I closed my laptop lid, the laptop would suspend. However, it doesn't do so now. The laptop heats up noticeably, and I get multiple windows asking me to enter passwords for wifi and telling me that the computer will suspend due to inactivity. This only seems to happen when the laptop is running on battery. Options in power settings are set to suspend on closing lid, both when running on AC and battery.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend or hibernate problems on any OS it's generated from bad drivers. See what differences is between power settings on battery and on AC and try to make, one by one, the battery settings to be like AC settings and when you see that your laptop it's ok than look what was the last modification and change for that device the driver. If you can't find a better driver for that device your only option remain to downgrade to 13.04. I hope that was usefull.